# Ionic Framework - Buttons inside form labels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a form like below,

```
<form>
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
            <input type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-button-right">
            Photo
            <button style="right: 95px;" class="button button-small button-clear" ng-click="get_gallery();">
                Gallery
            </button>
            <button class="button button-small button-clear" ng-click="get_camera();">
                Camera
            </button>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

The Problem is that whatever the button I hit, it always triggers `get_gallery()` method and never calls `get_camera()`. Can you someone help me what is the problem? I have also tried in other way which will look like,

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    Receipt
   <div>
        <button class="button button-small button-clear" ng-click="get_gallery();">
            Gallery
        </button>
        <button class="button button-small button-clear" ng-click="get_camera();">
            Camera
        </button>
    </div>
</label>
```

Am I doing something wrong? What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: why both buttons inside one label? Have you tried to change this?

I suggest change label to div with the same classes "item item button-right"

Comment: Yup, change the label to a div and it will work.

Comment: Oops, got the problem! it is a silly question. I've started using this framework for couple of days. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Just a little insight to this - <label> in ionic is designed in a way that when you tap anywhere inside the label, it is like tapping on the first input element inside it. It should be used only for single input fields. If you put two buttons there and click on the second button, it is in fact registered as click on <label> which activates the first input element which is the first button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change label tag to div, that will help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because the use two `button` in a `label` you can use two `lable` or replace `div` instead `lable` like this

```
<form>
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
            <input type="text">
        </label>
        <div style="display:inline-block" class="item item-button-right">
            Photo
            <button style="right: 95px;" class="button button-small button-clear" ng-click="get_gallery();">
                Gallery
            </button>
            <button class="button button-small button-clear" ng-click="get_camera();">
                Camera
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a button inside a label in Ionic, you can change `ng-click` to `ng-mousedown` on your button.

```
<label class="item item-button-right">
     Photo
    <button class="..." ng-mousedown="get_gallery();">
       Gallery
    </button>
    <button class="..." ng-mousedown="get_camera();">
       Camera
    </button>
</label>
```